# Bicep deployment failing template validation for single environment

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have a bicep template which references a set of modules to ultimately deploy Azure Front Door with custom domains, a set of DNS Zones and then create the TXT record for the custom domain validation. In other environments this has worked perfectly fine, but when deploying to production the deployment fails for the following reason:

```json
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "target": "/subscriptions/[subscription id]/resourceGroups/[resource group]/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/myCustomDomain",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "InvalidTemplate",
      "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The value for the template parameter 'validationToken' at line '1' and column '737' is not provided. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file for usage details.'.",
      "additionalInfo": [
        {
          "type": "TemplateViolation",
          "info": {
            "lineNumber": 1,
            "linePosition": 737,
            "path": "properties.template.parameters.validationToken"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The verification process is referenced via a module and has a `validationToken` parameter, so the error suggests that the validation token is not being supplied, but the validation token is supplied via `myCustomDomain.properties.validationProperties.validationToken` from a `Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/customDomains` resource:

```
resource customDomain 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/customDomains@2022-11-01-preview' = {
  name: domainResourceName
  parent: frontDoor
  properties: {
    hostName: domain.name
    azureDnsZone: {
      id: dns.id
    }
    tlsSettings: {
      certificateType: 'CustomerCertificate'
      minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS12'
      secret: {
        id: frontDoorSecret.id
      }
    }
  }
}

module verification 'myverificationmodule.bicep' = {
  name: 'verification-${domainResourceName}'
  scope: resourceGroup(domain.subscriptionId, domain.resourceGroup)
  params: {
    customDomainStatus: customDomain.properties.domainValidationState
    dnsZone: domain.name
    validationToken: customDomain.properties.validationProperties.validationToken
  }
}
```

Is there a race condition or some other reason why this would fail only in a single environment?

Comment: does it fail consistently on this environment ? could be some transient errors

Comment: It fails consistently for that environment. If you delete a front door resource with the custom domains validated and then recreate it, does this create the domains with no validation token? That is the only difference between the environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon investigation, it would appear that the validationToken is null if the domain has previously been deleted after validation and then re-created. In my case, I had deployed the Azure Front Door resource and all the required domains. I then deleted the resource until a later date, which is when I encountered this issue. I have now applied logic around the domain validation state to determine if the verification module should be used or not